# How to use same view model with different view in xml - WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

what I want to do is something like this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>       
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GraphXYLineViewModel}" >            
            <local:GraphXYLineView />
        </DataTemplate>


 </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding IsNotFreezeViewer, Converter={local:BoolToVisibleCollapsedConverter}}" >
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding GraphXYLineViewModel}" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding IsFreezeViewer, Converter={local:BoolToVisibleCollapsedConverter}}" >
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding GraphXYLineFreezeViewModel}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I want 2 view to view sometimes GraphXYLineViewModel and sometimes the GraphXYLineFreezeViewModel,
but when I try to show the second view I get nothing, is it because it is the same type of view model?

in view model they look like this:

```
    GraphXYLineViewModel _graphXYLineVM;
    GraphXYLineViewModel _graphXYLineFreezeVM;

    public IPageViewModel GraphXYLineViewModel
        {
            get{
                return (IPageViewModel)_graphXYLineVM;
            }
        }

    public IPageViewModel GraphXYLineFreezeViewModel
    {
        get{
            return (IPageViewModel)_graphXYLineFreezeVM;
        }
    }
```

how can i set it to work?

Comment: A **property name** is not a **type**

Comment: thanks, I called my types and view models in the same names

Comment: There is no type called GraphXYLineViewModel or GraphXYLineFreezeViewModel in the code you're showing, just two properties with these names. So what are you asking about?

Comment: I edit my question @Clemens

Comment: no @Clemens, I want them to be from the same type, is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two view model instances of the same type and want to show either the one or the other in the same view, you do not need two view model properties.

It seems sufficient to have a single property that holds either the one or the other view model instance. It must however fire a property change notification in order to update the view (e.g. the `PropertyChanged` event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface):

```
private IPageViewModel graphXYLineViewModel;

public IPageViewModel GraphXYLineViewModel
{
    get { return graphXYLineViewModel; }
    set
    {
        graphXYLineViewModel = value;

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GraphXYLineViewModel)));
    } 
}
```

The code to change the property would be something like this:

```
GraphXYLineViewModel = IsFreezeViewer ? _graphXYLineFreezeVM : _graphXYLineVM;
```

Since your UserControl would contain nothing more than

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding GraphXYLineViewModel}" />
```

it seems also questionable if you need it at all.

Comment: you made it clearer for me, I wanted at the beginning to have them both one on top the other, but now I only update them both data in their view models, and swap between them when I want freeze view or live view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding GraphXYLineViewModel}">
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:GraphXYLineView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFreezeViewer}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:GraphXYLineFreezeView />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Or just code a `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: There doesn't actually seem to be two different views or DataTemplates. The question is confusing, but (as far as I understand) it's just the same view with two different view model instances (of the same type).